# regex to extract string before uppercase word using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I need to extract the character before the first uppercase word using XSLT.

Input:

```
<au>Lmie Huke THE AUSTRALIAN UNIVERSITY and OXFORD</au>
```

Expected output:

```
<au>Lmie Huke</au>
```

Anyone please suggest.

Comment: Can you say whether you are using XSLT 1.0 or XSLT 2.0?

Comment: I am using XSLT 2.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use

```
  <xsl:template match="au">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:value-of select="let $w := tokenize(., '\s+') return $w[position() lt index-of($w, $w[. = upper-case(.)][1])]"/>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
```

in XSLT 3 or

```
  <xsl:template match="au">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:variable name="w" select="tokenize(., '\s+')"/>
          <xsl:value-of select="$w[position() lt index-of($w, $w[. = upper-case(.)][1])]"/>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
```

in XSLT 2 then for your input I think it works. It all depends on what constitutes a word and whether the kind of white space between words matters and needs to be preserved.

Comment: It's fine, but one more need is the uppercase word should more one digit. Now the string is selecting single digit uppercase word. e.g <au>Lmie Huke J THE AUSTRALIAN</au>. Now the initial was considered.

Comment: Then change `index-of($w, $w[. = upper-case(.)][1])]` to `index-of($w, $w[string-length(.) gt 1 and . = upper-case(.)][1])]`.